# toggle specific element with the same class names

Tags: jquery, html

how to toggle specific div with same class name when title is click content display i have 5 of this with the same class name problem is when i click one of the title all of the content displays.

```
    <div class="row package-row">
      <div class="global-switch">
            <input type="checkbox" id="switch1" name="switch1" class="switch" />
            <label for="switch1">Hide Packages</label>
      </div><!--end of global-switch-->
      <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="header-details">
                   <h3 id="toggle-h3-package">TITLE</h3>
                   <p>DESCRIPTION</p>
            </div>
            <div class="global-control" id="global-control">
                   CONTENT
            </div>
      </div>            
</div>
```

> jQuery Code

```
$('#toggle-h3-package').click(function(){
                $(this).parent().next('.global-control').animate({
                    height:'toggle',
                    opacity:'toggle'
                },500);
            });
```

Comment: `$('.className').toggle()` :)

Comment: i tried but when i click the first group i display the contents but the others wont display. :( @JeremyThille

Comment: ID must be unique, change that for a class and everything should work.

Comment: and also you should use some punctuation in your sentences because when it gets really long and you know there s a period but we don t know we have to guess where the end is and it s not easy to read I mean it would be easier if there were periods and commas and we don t really know the sentence is over and we have to put it back together I believe it s just common sense when you try to communicate with others ask their help don t you think